# Not receiving ModelState error when ommitting int property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I found some functionality in MVC4 that confuses me. I have the following model and controller action:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Foo { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel model)
{
    // check ModelState.IsValid and do stuff
}
```

The issue I'm running into is that if I do a GET request to MyAction and don't pass in any parameters then ModelState.IsValid is true. If I pass in Foo as a param with an empty string as the value then the ModelState.IsValid is false as expected (with the error message that Foo is required).

So I guess my question is why is ModelState.IsValid true when Foo is ommitted? Is this a bug in MVC or am I just missing something? If a property is required it seems like there should be a ModelState error when that property is ommitted.

Just for kicks I tried changing Foo to a string and added the [Required] attribute to it. When I did this both of the above tests returned false for ModelState.IsValid which is what I would expect it to do for a non-nullable int property as well. After this test I changed Foo back to an int and left the [Required] attribute to see if that had any effect. Still got the same results as when it was an int without the [Required] attribute.

Comment: Are you sure that `Foo` is null when you omit it, or has it defaulted to 0? I'm guessing `Foo` would be 0 and without the `[Required]` attribute it would pass validation.

Comment: @Brandon I never said Foo was null when ommitted. It is 0 in both cases, but only one of those cases throws a ModelState error. And when ommitted it passes validation with or without the [Required] attribute (when Foo is an int).

Comment: I guess the difference is that, a non-nullable `int` will have a value in the model when its passed through without the field in the markup.. that being zero. A `string` however, will be `null` if its not passed through in the markup. Makes sense to me (not a bug).

Comment: @SimonWhitehead So how would you go about making an int required so that it gives you a ModelState error when ommitted and when submitted as an empty form parameter? I've seen that it can be done with a string property but am so far unable to do it with an int property.

Comment: What about marking a nullable `int` with the `[Required]` attribute? That, to me, seems like it would have the same effect.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead from a conceptual point of view, if you specify in your model that a field is required (implicitly, in this case, by having it be non-nullable), then not providing a value for that in your http request should mean the state of the model is not valid...  It seems counter-intuitive to have a non-nullable value allow nulls, which is what this behavior indicates.

Comment: @DMactheDestroyer I don't disagree with you.. but think of it from a validation point of view. How do you know that it wasn't supplied? `int` defaults to 0. By the time you get your hands on it at validation-time it has a value. How do you know it wasn't passed by the form as 0? You can't... that's just how it is unfortunately. The Model Binder comes before the validation. Seems like a chicken and egg scenario to me.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead The framework should know it's not supplied by checking the raw request parameters that were sent (i.e. Request.QueryString). I would think at the time of model binding it would be able to see that this property is not in the raw values and add a ModelState error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to take a stab in the dark, I'd say that this is the point of code in the `DefaultModelBinder` class that causes this situation to occur:

```
    protected virtual void BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor)
    {
        // need to skip properties that aren't part of the request, else we might hit a StackOverflowException
        string fullPropertyKey = CreateSubPropertyName(bindingContext.ModelName, propertyDescriptor.Name);
        if (!bindingContext.ValueProvider.ContainsPrefix(fullPropertyKey))
        {
            return;
        }
```

If the property name isn't provided in the ValueProvider (which is just the request parameters in the most simple case), then it skips it... apparently to prevent infinite recursion in some cases.  I suppose that would make sense in the case of a nested model, for example:

```
class Foo
{
    public Foo InnerFoo { get; set; }
}
```

It seems a little shortsighted (or maybe my diagnosis is a little shortsighted...) to do it this way, namely because of situations like this exact post.

I'm calling it a bug, unless someone smarter can correct me.

The appropriate workaround would be as @Brandon's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21740835/437456) suggests:

```
[Required]
public int? Foo { get; set; }
```

and then keep on with life... we've all written much uglier stuff than that I'm sure :)

Answer (score 4):

What Simon said in the comments is correct.

If you don't pass an `int` to the model it just defaults to 0, whereas a string will pass in as null and fail the `Required` check.

If you want to enforce an integer you should use a nullable type. This way it ensures it defaults to null and not 0.

```
[Required]
public int? Foo { get; set; }
```

Comment: This does technically work, but it feels like a bit of a hack to get around a bug. Seems a little backwards making something nullable but then saying it's required.